# What are the assembly types with name <>c?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm loading some assembly types of my Entities and some of then appears with this value "<>c" in the name

what are these types? And how do I ignore them? (whitout load it) If i need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're C#-compiler-generated types, e.g. for anonymous types, iterator blocks, closures that capture local variables, and async functions. This is nothing to do with Entity Framework in itself.

If you want to ignore all compiler-generated types, you can check whether the type has the [`[CompilerGenerated]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) applied to it. If you want to do it just from the name, then see whether the name contains `<` or `>` - if it does, it's not a valid C# type name, and will have been autogenerated.